# What landings beyond Mars and the Moon are scheduled?

Tags: future-missions, lander

Recent years have brought us some interesting landings: Titan, the comet, the Chinese landed on the Moon, we got a lab the size of a SUV on Mars.

Currently, Mars is in the focus of the West, while India and China are targeting the Moon. Are there any landers scheduled (developed, underway, or at least fleshed out in plans) to any other bodies though?

Budget-approved missions are preferred, but others may be included as well as long as their non-approved status is clearly indicated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Feel free to edit this answer to add more or adjust formatting. List may be incomplete.

Ordered by launch date:

- [Hayabusa 2 and MASCOT to 162173 Ryugu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayabusa_2), Japan/Germany/France, launched 2014, landed three rovers in 2018 (fourth rover failed but was released to briefly orbit the asteroid in 2019).
  Hayabusa 2 departed November 2019 and returned to do an Earth flyby
  and sample return December 2020.
  The mission has been extended, and Hayabusa 2 will now make additional flybys (but no landings) of other asteroids in 2026 and 2031.
- [OSIRIS-REx to 101955 Bennu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSIRIS-REx), USA, launched 2016, contacted April 2020 as part of a sample collection rehearsal, and after further contacts for collection, closed its sample return capsule October 2020, return capsule will reenter Earth's atmosphere September 2023
- [ASTER probe to 2001 SN263](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/1866/58), Brazil, launch 2022, arrive 2025, awaiting funding
- [DART to the moon of 65803 Didymos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AIDA_%28mission%29), NASA, launch between November 2021 and February 2022, impact October 2022 (ESA's simultaneous orbiter Hera is scheduled to arrive later, possibly delaying also DART)
- [Lucy to Trojans sharing orbit with Jupiter](https://science.slashdot.org/story/17/01/05/0152213/nasa-unveils-two-new-missions-to-study-truly-strange-asteroids) NASA Launch oct. 2021, arrival 2027-2033.
- [Jupiter Icy Moon Explorer (JUICE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter_Icy_Moon_Explorer#Ganymede_Lander), ESA/Russia, launch 2022, l̶a̶n̶d̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶2̶0̶3̶3̶, originally proposed to include a Russian lander on Ganymede (the mission was selected, the lander portion will likely be spun off as a separate mission, see Laplace-P)
- [Psyche to Psyche (210km metallic asteroid in the Asteroid Belt)](https://science.slashdot.org/story/17/01/05/0152213/nasa-unveils-two-new-missions-to-study-truly-strange-asteroids) NASA, Launch 2022, arrival 2026
- [Europa Clipper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europa_Multiple-Flyby_Mission), previously Europa Multiple-Flyby Mission, USA, launch around 2024, arrive in a few years, proposed lander split off to separate mission (see below)
- [Fobos-Grunt 2 to Phobos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fobos-Grunt#Repeat_mission), Russia, launch 2024, awaiting reapproval
- [Europa Lander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europa_Lander_(NASA)), NASA, launch 2025, arrive and landing about 2030, awaiting funding
- [Venera-D to Venus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venera-D), Russia, launch around 2026, in preliminary design but implementation has been delayed
- [Laplace-P to Ganymede](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace-P), Russia, proposed launch 2026, proposed landing 2030, awaiting funding
- [Mission to Uranus and or Neptune about 2030](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/nasa-completes-study-of-future-ice-giant-mission-concepts) is under study by NASA (full report pdf is [here](https://www.lpi.usra.edu/icegiants/mission_study/Full-Report.pdf))
- [CNSA Ceres probe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceres_%28dwarf_planet%29#Exploration), China, launch around 2020s, not yet approved
- [PRIME to Phobos](http://www.spaceref.com/news/viewpr.html?pid=22554), Canada, not yet approved
- [TALISE to Titan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_Lake_In-situ_Sampling_Propelled_Explorer), Spain, not yet approved

Stretching the definition of "landing" a little bit, there could also be our first "landing" (in the sense of arrival) at another star system:

- [Breakthrough Starshot to Alpha Centauri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakthrough_Starshot), international effort by Breakthrough Initiatives, launch around 2036, arrive between 2056-2066 (communication of successful arrival would take another 4 years), in research phase

Comment: I would delete Laplas-P. There was a mission design study, but in 2017 it was deferred. There is no money and no technological readiness (rad-hardened electronics, etc). Source (in Russian): https://tass.ru/interviews/4411146

Comment: @Heopps A few of these have no money or readiness. Unless it has been definitively canceled, I'll leave it. That said, I will update to say that the funding is no longer approved.