# What's up with Brazil's ASTER mission? Is it still scheduled to launch in June 2020?

Tags: launch, asteroid

This [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/1876/12102) says:

> Brazil is currently planning its first deep space mission to the triple asteroid 2001 SN263. The mission, named ASTER, has a launch opportunity in June 2020.

and links to [Reviewed plan of the ALR, the laser rangefinder for the
ASTER deep space mission to the triple asteroid 2001-SN263](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/911/1/012016/pdf) .

Is it still on schedule to launch in June 2020? Has a launch provider been chosen yet?

Comment: Wikipedia is reporting a scheduled 2021 launch now, but the source link is broken.

Comment: @called2voyage it certainly seems like a pretty ambitious first mission.

Comment: I updated my original answer, which you link to, with the new date.

Comment: I won't post this as an answer as I can't provide reliable sources yet, but I know that it won't be launching in 2021, unless something radically changes in the next few months. We're actually waiting for an announcement on it soon.

Comment: @Yuri-M-Dias I thought that might be the case. A little late to still have no budget.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this source the launch is planned in 2021

https://iepc2017.org/sites/default/files/speaker-papers/phall_for_deep_space_mission_at_iepc_2017_final_1.docx